# KDE color scheme is not applying

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde, colors

I installed `kubuntu-desktop` and color themes are not working.

When I change for example from `Breeze` to `Breeze Dark` in Color section in the settings nothing except title bar color seems to change.

Tried restarting/logging out but the window content stays bright. Some sections of the UI seem to have color scheme applied but it doesn't look right.

Here is the screenshot of the only place which had colors partly applied to it.

[image]

Here is my preferences in the Konsole:

[image]

How can I do so that the whole window has dark theme?

Answer (score 0):

My problem seemed to be related: [Kubuntu Breeze-Dark not working as expected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774264/kubuntu-breeze-dark-not-working-as-expected)

I"ve also been upgrading from Ubuntu to Kubuntu. However, using the newest version of 5.6 of plasma from backports-landing resolved this issue.