# Kubuntu Breeze-Dark not working as expected

Tags: kubuntu, kde, colors

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04.

When I tried switching to breeze-dark I applied the following steps:

Go to system settings --> workspace theme. Change to breeze dark. Go to color, double check that breeze dark is selected. Then apply.

However, even after a reboot the color scheme of the windows (especially KDE/QT) did not change, whereas most of  the "outer" appearance like the panel, the launcher, etc. got changed to the dark scheme.

Can you give any advice how to track down the problem?

[image: Screenshot of a partly adapted window]

Comment: Updating to plasma 5.6 from backports-landing seems to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to plasma 5.12 from [Kubuntu Backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) seems to resolve the problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
```

Comment: Even version 5.8 was enough to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Anwar answered in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812270/color-problem-on-kubuntu-16-04):

I had the same problem as you, and switching to breeze dark in gnome application settings worked for me.

Hope it helps.